# PHP echo filename into img src

Tags: php

I have a image filename stored and i want to echo it into some code where it will be a hyperlink to another page but it also gets the filename from the stored data.

```
echo " <a href=\"ProductDescription.php?productid=" . $row['productid'] . \" >
<img src=\"/admin/images/ . $row['image'] . \" alt=\"product image\" width=\"40\"
height=\"65\"></a> ";
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING
```

I just can't seem to figure out my syntax problem to get it to work.

Comment: You've escaped a double-quote at the end of the first line. Is that a typo?

Comment: Spend a few minutes and you'll figure it out. Oh never mind, the Calvary's come to your rescue below.

Comment: That many escape characters is a pet peeve of mine, just use bloody single quotes! You're not even embedding any variables into the string  anyway so what's the point???

Comment: I like the change in title

Comment: There's no need to update the title of a question to mark it solved. Please mark it solved by selecting an answer. (Hit the green checkmark next to the answer you think is best.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the " after productid. And also forgot to add it around image.

Do it via:

```
echo "<a href=\"ProductDescription.php?productid=$row['productid']\"><img src=\"/admin/images/$row['image']\" alt=\"product image\" width=\"40\" height=\"65\"></a>";
```

Or

```
echo " <a href=\"ProductDescription.php?productid=" . $row['productid'] . "\" ><img src=\"/admin/images/" . $row['image'] . "\" alt=\"product image\" width=\"40\" height=\"65\"></a> ";
```

Comment: That works brilliantly thanks. Will mark as answer when its available

Answer (score 1):

just check your double-quotes

```
echo " <a href=\"ProductDescription.php?productid=" . $row['productid'] . " /><img src=\"/admin/images/ ". $row['image'] . "\" alt=\"product image\" width=\"40\" height=\"65\"></a> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the error:

```
echo " <a href=\"ProductDescription.php?productid=" . $row['productid'] . " \" ><img src=\"/admin/images/" . $row['image'] ."\" alt=\"product image\" width=\"40\"
height=\"65\"></a> ";
```